# terminal connection from a different local IP other than the primary IP

Tags: linux, networking, ip

I have ~20 public IP addresses defined on my server. Now, when I connect to a remote server via terminal, it gets connected from the primary IP of my server.

But I want to use terminal from my another IP address. Is this possible?

Comment: What do you mean by "via terminal"? Are you looking for a way to change the source IP address of all connections to a particular machine? Or are you looking for a way to invoke a specific program so that it makes a connection from a particular IP address? Or something else entirely?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I meant "telnet", not "terminal".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using ssh to connect to the remote host then you can use the `BindAddress` directive to specify a local address to us for the connection

> BindAddress
>                Use the specified address on the local machine as the source address of the connection.  Only useful on systems
>                with more than one address.  Note that this option does not work if UsePrivilegedPort is set to “yes”.

You can use this like so

```
ssh user@remote.tld -o BindAddress=ip.add.re.ss
```

You can also configure your [~/.ssh/config](http://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config) file to do this on a per host basis.

```
Host remote.tld
    BindAddress ip.add.re.ss

Host another
    BindAddress ss.er.dda.pi
```

Note that the Host matched has to be the same as that specified on the command line but you can use wildcards.

---

If you're using [telnet](http://linux.die.net/man/1/telnet) then use the -b switch

> -b address
>                Use bind(2) on the local socket to bind it to a specific local
>                address.

```
telnet -b ip.add.re.ss remote.tld
```

Comment: @lain, thanks for your answer. What about telnet?

Comment: @Cem: updated my answer

Comment: Bind option is not available to me. Why?
`telnet [-4] [-6] [-8] [-E] [-K] [-L] [-N] [-S tos] [-X atype] [-c] [-d]
 [-e char] [-k realm] [-l user] [-f/-F] [-n tracefile] [-r] [-s src_addr] [-u] [-P policy] [host-name [port]]`